# React js receiving props from child component to mother component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let, we have a parent component like this,

```
import React from 'react';

export default class ParentComp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='padding'>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Okay, now i want to use this component like this

```
<ParentComp fillbg="#389457">
      content goes here.......
</ParentComp>
```

What needs to be changed in parent component to apply that background (fillbg)

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react'

export default const ParentComp = ({children, fillbg}) => (
    <div className='padding' style={{backgroundColor: fillbg}}>
        {children}
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as prop to your component and use it

```
import React from 'react';

export default class ParentComp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='padding' style={{backgroundColor: this.props.fillbg}}>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Pass the fillbg prop like this

```
<ParentComp fillbg="#389457">
      content goes here.......
</ParentComp>
```